# PHP正規表現で、「タブ区切り」から「タブ区切り」までを選択して、前後にdivタグを挿入

Tags: php, 正規表現

■対象

```
$hoge="××××

tab→    抽出抽出    ←tab

××××××";
```

---

■やりたいこと1
・PHP正規表現で、「タブ区切り」から「タブ区切り」までを選択して、前後にdivタグを挿入したい

・うまくいかないコード

```
preg_replace(/\t(.*?)\t)/m, "<div>$1</div>", $hoge);
```

・希望結果1

```
$hoge="××××

tab→<div>抽出抽出</div>←tab

××××××";
```

---

■やりたいこと2
・PHP正規表現で、「空行」から「空行」までを選択して、前後にdivタグを挿入したい

・うまくいかないコード

```
preg_replace(/^\n(.*?)^\n)/m, "<div>$1</div>", $hoge);
```

・希望結果2

```
$hoge="××××
<div>
tab→    抽出抽出    ←tab
</div>
××××××";
```

Comment: 期待する出力例を具体的に書いていただきたいです。

Comment: 「やりたいこと2」で期待する出力結果は、`<div>抽出
抽出抽出</div>`です。現時点で一番知りたいことは、「空行で囲まれた文字列」へマッチするPHP正規表現パターンです

Comment: 前後の`xxxxx`は不要なのでしょうか。`$hoge`と見比べやすいように、コメントではなく質問の方に出力例を追記していただけませんか？

Comment: 空行間にマッチする正規表現文字列というのであれば、`'/(?<=\n\n)(.*)(?=\n\n)/s'`で取れませんかね？

Comment: コメントいただいた「空行間にマッチする正規表現」で無事取得できました！大変参考になりましたー

Comment: @re9 本質問が既に解決済みの場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

■ 1つ目

```
$hoge="××××

tab→    抽出抽出    ←tab

××××××";

echo "\nbefore:\n", $hoge;
$replace = preg_replace('/\t([^\t]+)\t/', '<div>$1</div>', $hoge);
echo "\nafter:\n", $replace;
```

で、こんなのが得られるのでは所望の動きではないでしょうか？

```
before:
××××

tab→   抽出抽出        ←tab

××××××
after:
××××

tab→<div>抽出抽出</div>←tab

××××××
```

■ 2つ目
(2015-02-12 11:41 編集)
手直ししてみました。こういう事がやりたいんですかね？
ちょっと自分の実力では1つの正規表現では表しきれなかったです。(´・ω・`)

```
<?php
$hoge="××××

tab→    抽出 抽出
抽出    ←tab

××××××";

echo "\nbefore:\n", $hoge;
$replace = preg_replace('/(?<=\n\n)(.*)(\n)(.*)(?=\n\n)/s', '$1 $3', $hoge);
$replace = preg_replace('/\n\n(.+)\n\n/s', '<div>$1</div>', $replace);
echo "\nafter:\n", $replace;
?>
```

で、こんなのが得られるのでは所望の動きではないでしょうか？

```
before:
××××

tab→   抽出 抽出
抽出    ←tab

××××××
after:
××××<div>tab→      抽出 抽出 抽出  ←tab</div>××××××
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。■1つ目の正規表現パターンは、希望結果を取得することができました。大変参考になりました。■2つ目の正規表現パターンは、希望結果を取得することができませんでした。一致しません

Comment: 手直してみました。これで所望の動きになりますかね？
ちょっと冗長な気がするし、なにより2stepになっちゃいましたけど...

Comment: コメントに書いてあったから改行消えてただけだったのかな？
空行間の改行消さなくて良いのであれば、`$replace = preg_replace('/\n\n(.+)\n\n/s', '<div>$1</div>', $hoge);`だけで済む話な気がします。

Comment: 回答編集ありがとうございました。無事に期待結果を取得できたのですが、内容を理解できません。(?<=\n\n)(.*)(\n)(.*)(?=\n\n)はどういう意味なのでしょうか？

Comment: `'/(?<=\n\n)(.*)(?=\n\n)/s'` について説明します。  
まず、末尾のsはマッチする対象に改行が含まれても良いように付けてます。で、上記には3つの括弧があるのがわかると思いますが、それぞれグルーピングしています。真ん中の`(.*)`は問題無いと思います。分からないのは`(?<=\n\n)`と`(?=\n\n)`だと思いますが、`\n\n`の部分はLF2回を表してるだけなので問題無いですよね。  
`(?<=)`と`(?=)`の部分ですが、正規表現には先読み、後読みとか呼ばれる機能があります。文字列検索をしてると同じ文字列なんだけど、前や後にhogeって文字列がある場合だけマッチしたいって事がありますよね？要は検索条件には含まれるけど、一致する文字列として含まれない文字列を指定する事ができる機能です。今回の場合は、前に空行(LF2回)が来て、後ろに空行(LF2回)が来るの間に含まれる任意の文字列`(.*)`をマッチさせたかった訳ですから...先読みに`\n\n`を設定して、後読みにも`\n\n`を設定した訳です。  
http://php.net/manual/ja/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: 「詳細な解説」&「リンク提示」ありがとうございました。(?<=)(?=)はそれぞれ「先読み、後読み」なんですね。大変勉強になりましたー

Answer (score 1):

これ、どうしても一つの文でreplaceしないといけないのですか？
preg_matchでtabで区切り、採れたものにdivと/divを前後につけてつなぎ直すほうがシンプルでいいと思いますが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。replaceではなくてpreg_matchでもOKです。「タブ区切り」については「豚吐露」さんから回答いただいた正規表現パターンで解決しました。現在は「空行で囲まれた文字列」へマッチするPHP正規表現パターンを試行錯誤しています

Answer (score 1):

```
$hoge = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r/', "\n", $hoge);
$replace = preg_replace('/(?:\n\n)(.+?)(?=\n\n)/s', '<div>$1</div>', $hoge);
```

改行がプラットフォームによってまちまちなので\nに統一してから、空行で挟まれた部分を抽出しています。最後の「?=」は肯定先読みで、「空行 抽出部分1 空行 抽出部分2 空行・・・」みたいな感じでもうまく抽出できるようにしています。

どうも冗長な感じがするのでもう少し短くできるような気もしますが…

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。期待結果を無事取得することができました！が、2行目のコードが難しいです。?:はキャプチャしない丸括弧だと思うのですが、(\n\n)はどういう意味でしょうか？ 1空行もしくは2空行？